# URI Scheme for Microsoft Equalizer app on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, launch, equalizer, lumia

This is a question for an old platform, but I happen to need to write an app for Windows Phone 8.1. This app needs to launch the Microsoft Equalizer (audio) app that could be installed on some Nokia Lumia devices and enabled audio equalizer in the phone's Settings section.

I know I need the app's URI scheme to launch it through code, but I can't find the scheme for [this particular app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/equaliser/9nblggh319dl?rtc=1) anywhere.
Also I know for a fact that it is possible to launch this app because [there are other apps on the Store that can do that](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/audio-equalizer/9wzdncrd3c3n).

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me the URI scheme - or any other way - to launch the equalizer app on a Windows Phone 8.1 device.

Comment: try await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("equalizer://Launch")); OR await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:extras-equalizer")); . I used WP 8.1 long time ago. Please avoid syntax or launcher code. Let me know if works or not.

Comment: "equalizer://Launch" is the URI Scheme for the other app that I mentioned in the post, meaning that app ("Audio Equalizer") needs to be installed for this scheme to work.
As for your other suggestion "ms-settings:extras-equalizer", it doesn't work. The "search for app in the store" message appears indicating the scheme is not known by the device.
I'd really appreciate it if you could look in your code to find what the real URI Scheme is.

Comment: MS equalizer app is 3rd party app. I meant we need to download it and install it separately from store. It will be placed under settings > Extras. Please try "ms-settings:extras" schema to open extra apps under settings. Meanwhile I will try to look into it.

Comment: Yes I understand, but MS equalizer comes preinstalled on supported Lumia devices and gets updated through the Store. That isn't what I meant. "equalizer://Launch" is the URI scheme for a non-Microsoft non-Nokia app that can launch the MS equalizer app. Its developer just figured since the real URI scheme isn't documented anywhere and he has it, he can make a buck by making everyone install his app. That's what I was referring to.
I need the real MS equalizer app's URI scheme.
I tested "ms-settings:extras" on my Lumia 1320 and again, it is not a recognized scheme.

Comment: I am trying to find it out because now it became interesting to get this. Till now no luck. I'll post once getting something useful.